# Django template {% include not working

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I'm new to Django. I'm having problem including a sub-template in a main template. The directory structure of my project is attached in the snapshot. I removed the default views.py and created my own folder named "views" and put my views in it. Here is what I've done:

**1. app/views/__init__.py**

```
from .home import *
```

**2. app/views/home.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render

def index(request):
    return render(request, 'home.html')
```

**3. app/templates/home.html**

```
{% load staticfiles %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>
    Administrator Section
</title>

<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="{% static "css/common.css" %}"/>
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="{% static "css/theme/transdmin.css" %}"/>
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="{% static "css/login.css" %}"/>

<script type="text/javascript" src="{% static "js/jquery-1.10.2.js" %}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{% static "js/common.js" %}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{% static "js/login.js" %}"></script>

</head>
<body>
<div>

<div id="wrapper" class="ys-adminform">

    {% include "includes.header_logo.html" %}

    <form id="form-login" class="admin-section-form frm">

        <div class="header">
            <br/>

            <h1>Login</h1>
            <br/>
        </div>

        <div class="content">

            <div class="form-row">
                <input name="email" class="input" placeholder="Email" type="text"/>

                <div class="user-icon"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-row">
                <input name="password" class="input password" placeholder="Password" type="password"/>

                <div class="pass-icon"></div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="footerlogin">
            <input class="button" name="btn-login" value="Authenticate" type="button"/>

            <div class="message" style="font-weight: bold; padding-top:16px;">&nbsp;</div>
        </div>

    </form>

</div>
</div>

{% include "includes.footer.html" %}
</body>
</html>
```

The problem is include is not adding content from the sub-views.
I understand it could be a path problem but I tried various options like:

```
{% include "includes.header_logo.html" %}

{% include includes.header_logo.html %}

{% include "includes/header_logo.html" %}

{% include "templates.includes.header_logo.html" %}

{% include "app.templates.includes.header_logo.html" %}
```

etc.

[image: Snapshot of project structure]

Comment: Can you pass one of included templates? And why you're not using `{% extends %}` template tag instead? It's better (and preferred in django) to have one base file and extend it with your code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use directory slashes (`/`), not dots (`.`)

For example:

```
{% include "includes.footer.html" %}
```

becomes this:

```
{% include "includes/footer.html" %}
```

Comment: I tried slash but same. Even it does not show any error. I hope you suggested after looking my directory structure in attached snapshot

Comment: Thanks Leistungsabfall, your solutions works. The image was causing the problem which I will check.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by Leistungsabfall, "includes/footer.html" works. The header was not working because it had:

This line must be crashing and because of which header was not working.

Answer (score 0):

Simply add template folder with slash .... like 
{% include "blog/footer.html" %}